# Proper Font style (size and alpha) for ios7 Footer and header

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uifont

I'm in the need to recreating the standard Header and Footer view in iOS7 but can't get the exact details of the text formatting.

Here's what I think:

Helvetica Neue (I'm using systemFontofSize ?)
size 14 for header???
size 12 for footer???

text.color = colorWithWhite 0.5 1.0?????

For the my custom view, I have obviously create a label...guessing on origin position:

iphone: 16, 18
ipad: 16, 10 seems to look right, but why the difference?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I can't find this info in the docs.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Note that their sizes change based on accessibility settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the solution here:

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

The font seems to be "HelveticaNeue-Light", 34px for the header and "HelveticaNeue", 28px for the footer.

Comment: 34px? Really? Maybe if you're pixel-counting, but if you set your font size to 34, it's _much_ larger than headings. What's that in points?